# Hazelcast [3.2.3] Remote socket closed Exception

Tags: hazelcast

I am getting the exception after every two minutes  in tomcat logs :

WARN  nio.ReadHandler [hz._hzInstance_1_xyz.IO.thread-in-2]  - [127.0.0.1]:5702 [xyz] [3.2.3] hz._hzInstance_1_xyz.IO.thread-in-2 Closing socket to endpoint Address[127.0.0.1]:5701, Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed!

Here is my hazelcast config

`<hz:hazelcast id="instance">
        <hz:config>
            <hz:group name="xyz" password="welcome" />
            <hz:properties>
                    <hz:property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</hz:property>
                    <hz:property name="hazelcast.shutdownhook.enabled">false</hz:property>
            </hz:properties>
            <hz:network port="5701" port-auto-increment="true">
                <hz:join>
                    <hz:multicast enabled="false" />
                    <hz:tcp-ip enabled="true">
                        <hz:members>127.0.0.1</hz:members>
                    </hz:tcp-ip>
                </hz:join>
            </hz:network>
            <hz:map name="xyzCache" async-backup-count="1" />
        </hz:config>
    </hz:hazelcast>`

Although everything is working fine but why this warning ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the pointing this issue. Later realized that one more service within the same tomcat was using hazelcast on the same port 5701 and hence the issue. Changed the port to 5703. And now everything work fine.

Letting this question, in case anyone else also hit the same issue. Thanks!